# position:fixed and width:auto

Tags: css, position, margin, fixed

I'm trying to do a layout combining a flexible column and elements with `position:fixed`. The idea is to have 2 columns, in the first one a `position: fixed menu`, in the second one is the **content** and a **text**. I want the text to be `position: fixed` so at the end the only thing that moves is the proper content. *The problem is the content width, it changes*, so I need the width of the content to be **auto** but when I combine the `width:auto` with the `position:fixed` its not working.

I think my explanation it's not clear enough so here is the code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="pageWrap">
        <div class="colLeft">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li>ELEMENT 1</li>
                    <li>ELEMENT 2</li>
                    <li>ELEMENT 3</li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="colContent">
            <div class="content">
<img width="300" height="200" alt="1" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nightlife-q-g-300-200-4.jpg">

<img width="300" height="200" alt="1" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nightlife-q-g-300-200-4.jpg">

<img width="300" height="200" alt="1" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nightlife-q-g-300-200-4.jpg">
            </div>
            <aside>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer 
                adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. 
                Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient 
                ridiculus mus. </p>        
            </aside>
        </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.pageWrap {
    width: 600px;
    height: 1000px;
    background-color: rgba(256, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

    .colLeft {
        width: 100px;
        float: left;

        height: 100px;
        background-color: rgba(0, 256, 0, 0.5);

    }
        nav{
            position:fixed;
            background-color: rgba(0, 256, 0, 0.5);
        }

    .colContent {
        width: 500px;

        float:left;
    }
        .content {
            float: left;
            width: auto;
        }
        aside {
            width: 200px;
            float:left;
            position:fixed;
        }
```

I want [this (JSFiddle)[http://jsfiddle.net/frMxW/2/] but with the aside `position:fixed` and that if I want to put smaller images the aside stay beside the content without a gap

Any idea how I can do that?

Thank you very much!

**UPDATE:** I tried this idea: putting the content and the aside to `display:inline-block`, seems to work in Chrome and Firefox (the aside stays there if I change the width of the image) *but* it's not working in Opera, and I can't try in IE. Here is my attempt: http://jsfiddle.net/9uGw4/7/

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you add jsfiddle, try not to add the same CSS/HTML code in the question!

Comment: OK sorry, I remove the html and css.

Comment: @LGAP That is just **wrong**. What if the JSFiddle link is removed? The question becomes _useless_ for future visitors. There is a reason why users are encouraged to put code in their questions

Answer (score 0):

[Updated] Does [this solution](http://jsfiddle.net/7QRv6/3/) works for you?

I fixed both `<aside>` and `colLeft`, and the width of the content is set to auto, with margins on both sides.

Comment: Hi thank you! But i think I wasn't clear enough. I want the aside to be fixed in the right

Comment: the problem is the gap between the content itself and the aside. I want to be able to put smaller or bigger images and that the aside stay there, beside the content.

Comment: this http://jsfiddle.net/frMxW/1/ but with the aside fix and the content "dynamic"

Comment: Do you want the `aside` overlaying the content? I don't get it

Comment: An image to be even more clear, if the content changes, the aside moves but stay fixed, maybe there is a complete different way to do this but i cant find it...

http://s9.postimage.org/ugdom8sxb/content.jpg

Comment: This is the idea http://jsfiddle.net/frMxW/2/ but the content width is 300px so if i put an image in the center with **300px width** its perfect but if i put an image with **100px width** i have a gap between the image and the aside. I want the aside to stay by the content no matter the size of it.

Comment: @user2083117 I don't think you can't do that, because the `position:fixed;` which is the only JS-less way to make a div's position independent of the page's scroll, is attached to the viewport.

It's not in the flow of the page anymore, so it won't adapt its position as in a normal div stack.

Have a look on JScript solutions, sorry for not being able to give you further help.

Comment: I have this idea that works in Chorme and Firefox but it's not working in Chome. http://jsfiddle.net/9uGw4/8/ any idea?